# How to show that the general Gaussian integral has positive real part?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds, gaussian-integral

Suppose $a$ is a complex number with positive real part (so $a$ is not necessarily just real). I am considering the integral
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}/(2a)} \, dx. $$
So far I was able to show (using the famous trick by Gauss)
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}/(2a)} \, dx = \pm``\sqrt{2\pi a}" $$
where $``\sqrt{2\pi a}"$ stands for the square-root with positive real part. My last step is to show the above equation must use the $+$ sign. This is obvious if $a$ is real and the LHS integral is entirely real, but I am not sure how to proceed if $a$ is complex with $\text{Re}(a) > 0$.

Am I missing something obvious? Any suggestions?

---

### Work So Far

Okay, here is one attempt I am pursuing. Write $a = |a|e^{i\phi}$. Then

\begin{align}
\exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2a}\right) &= \exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2|a|}e^{-i\phi}\right) = \exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2|a|}(\cos\phi - i\sin\phi)\right) \\
&= \exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2|a|}\cos\phi\right)\exp\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2|a|}i\sin\phi\right) \\
&= e^{-x^{2}\cos\phi/(2|a|)}\left( \cos\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2|a|}\sin\phi\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2|a|}\sin\phi\right) \right).
\end{align}
Thus the real part of the main integral is of the form
$$ A = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x^{2}}\cos(\beta x^{2}) \, dx $$
where $\alpha, \beta$ are real constants.

Now I won't go into detail here (unless someone asks for more details), but we can assume $\alpha > 0$. The possibility that $\phi = 0$ corresponds to the case where $a$ is real, which is trivial, so we assume $\phi\ne 0$. Thus, $\beta\ne 0$. If $\beta$ is negative, we can WLOG replace it by $-\beta$, because it appears inside a cosine function, which is an even function. Thus, we will assume $\alpha, \beta > 0$.

The integrand of $A$ is even in $x$, so we can write it as
$$ A = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha x^{2}}\cos(\beta x^{2}) \, dx. $$
Do a substitution of variables:
$$ x = \sqrt{y}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}}, \qquad dx = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\beta}}. $$
This gives
$$ A = 2\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\beta}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}e^{-\gamma y}\cos(y) \, dy $$
where $\gamma = \alpha/\beta$ is some positive constant.
The outside constant factor is irrelevant, so it all comes down to showing that
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}e^{-\gamma y}\cos(y) \, dy $$
is positive, where $\gamma > 0$. Is there any way to see that $I$ must be positive?

Comment: Try showing that $I_n = \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} e^{-p x^2}\cos(q x)dx$ is strictly decreasing in magnitude.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Check my new edit. The integral of interest is not the one you posted. You have to be more careful (or maybe I'm not seeing what you're seeing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sides are holomorphic functions of $a$ in the strict right-half plane (the left side due to Leibniz's integral rule, or Morera+Fubini) and the right by elementary considerations. They are clearly equal on the positive real axis, so must be equal everywhere in the right-half plane ('identity theorem').

Note that in order to obtain this equality, we must exploit the regularity of $a\mapsto\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{-x^2/2a}\,dx$, because if in general all you know is that a function satisfies $[f(a)]^2=2\pi a$, then there are two possibilities for $f(a)$, and it may even happen that $f(a_1)$ and $f(a_2)$ are given by two different branches of the square root. Above, I exploited analyticity, but continuity should suffice as well.